NSPredicate weird formatting behaviour
I am somewhat stuck trying to write a helper function for querying my CoreData store.
For simple things (like string values etc) the following syntax works well:
let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"myProperty == \(someString)")

However, it breaks if I try to say something like "self in \(arrayOfIDs)".
Here is a small reproducible example which breaks:
let ids = [1,2,3]
let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"self in \(ids)")

Running this code fails with libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException. Clearly, NSPredicate cannot be constructed in such a way.
I have figured out that the issue can be resolved if I actually use CVarArgs like so:
let ids = [1,2,3]
let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"self in %@", args: ids)

However, as I try to employ this in a function where I am going to pass predicate, I would like to avoid passing format and CVarArgs.
So my next logical assumption is that I could construct a String using String(format:String, args: any CVarArg...) and pass this as a predicate format without additional arguments.
Surprisingly, this breaks as well:
let ids = [1,2,3]
let predicate = NSPredicate(format:String(format:"self in %@", args: ids))

Does anyone have any idea how this could be resolved?
For context, this is the function which I am trying to write:
static func fetch<T:FetchDeclaringManagedObject>(_ request:NSFetchRequest<T>, predicate:String?, context:NSManagedObjectContext = defaultContext, sortDescriptors:[NSSortDescriptor]? = nil) -> [T] {
    let request = T.fetchRequest()
    if let p = predicate {
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: p)
    }
    // REST OF CODE
}

It would be super convenient if I did not have to rewrite it to specify both format and CVarArgs :)

The problem is your static func fetch<T:FetchDeclaringManagedObject>(_ request:NSFetchRequest<T>, predicate:String?.... No. That parameter needs to be an NSPredicate, not a string.

@matt I get it, but why does String(format:, args:) not produce the desired output? This whole format arga stuff is really Ovjective-Cish.

What are the values of "self in \(ids)", String(format:"self in %@", args: ids) and predicate.predicateFormat of the working NSPredicate? And yes, NSPredicate is Objective-C, but you can't use strings in Objective-C either.

@Willeke I’ve added the example. In reality I have an array of NSManagedObkectIDs. However, even an array of integers illustrates the problem. The code literally crashes unless NSPredicate is constructed with CVarArgs directly (constructing through String with CVarArgs also crashes)

NSPredicate can't parse incorrect format strings. See also NSPredicate - Unable to parse the format string.

Compare the output of String(format:"self in %@", args: ids) and NSPredicate(format: "self in %@", argumentArray: [ids]), print them in console. The output should be different, because the NSPredicate(format:) "re-parse" in fact and use specific format and not the default one of description.

So avoid passing a String Predicate, pass a NSPredicate. Create factories methods on it if needed, but "I'd strongly suggest to always go to Predicate, not String".

That function feels like over-generalization to me, but if you're set on having it, what I'd do is

Write a second function with almost the same arguments as that function, only with the predicate argument replaced with an argument that contains an array of IDs.
In that second function,

Create the predicate
Then, call the function you have above.



It's a little different when you call it, but since you apparently already have an array of IDs, this is the easy way to get things working.
